# It's possible to make a Batch program that backup a folder files from my external hd to pc hdd, anytime I add or change a file?

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, backup, hard-drive

I'm a graphic designer and I use my external hd frequently to move psd/jpeg/png/tiff files from my laptop at home to my Work PC and vice versa. But as a precaution before modifying or adding a file I copy it to a folder. It's possible to make it automatically? And it's easy to make on Batch?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, search for `robocopy schedule backup` here on stackoverflow or google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robocopy is your friend; google it and have a look. It's a very powerful program by sysinternals (owned by Microsoft). Alternatively, if you want a nice GUI to go with it use SyncToy (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15155) which can be run with a batch file (including arguments) or made into a scheduled task.